# Canonical divisor of $\mathbb{P}^2$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-forms, projective-space

I'm trying to understand the computation of the canonical divisor of $\mathbb{P}^2$.

The usual explanation goes like this:

> Let $(X:Y:Z)$ be the coordinates of $\mathbb{P}^2$. In the local chart $U_Z=\{Z\neq 0\}$, we define the coordinates $x:=\frac{X}{Z}$ and $y:=\frac{Y}{Z}$ and take the $2$-form $dx\wedge dy$, which has no zeros and no poles.
>
> In $U_Y:=\{Y\neq 0\}$, we define $u:=\frac{X}{Y}$, $v:=\frac{Z}{Y}$, so that:
>
> \begin{align*}
> dx\wedge dy&=d\left(\frac{u}{v}\right)\wedge d\left(\frac{1}{v}\right)\\
> &=\left(\frac{du}{v}-\frac{u}{v^2}dv\right)\wedge\left(-\frac{1}{v^2}dv\right)\\
> &=-\frac{1}{v^3}du\wedge dv
> \end{align*}
>
> which has a pole of order $3$, therefore $K_{\mathbb{P}^2}=-3H$, where $H$ is a hyperplane (in this case, a line).

What I don't understand about this argumentation is 1) why don't we need to check the other chart $U_X:=\{X\neq 0\}$? and 2) what is this $H$ exactly?

Comment: $k[X,Y,Z]$ is a UFD and its unique factorization is compatible with homogeneous polynomials, thus you can interpret the unique factorization $v=Z/Y$ as giving directly the divisor $div(v) = (Z)-(Y)$, where $(Z)= \{ [X:Y:Z],Z=0\}$. It is not true that $dx\land dy$ has no pole, it has no pole on the copy of $\Bbb{A}^2$ you are looking at which is $A_Z= \{ [X:Y:Z],Z=1\}$, but in $A_Y$ it has a triple pole at $(v)$ (prime ideal of $k[u,v]$) ie. a triple pole on $\Bbb{P}^2$ at $(Z)=H$ (irreducible closed subvariety of codimension 1)

Comment: $\Bbb{P}^2 = A_Z\cup (Z)$ and you have found the restriction of $div(dx\land dy)$ on each subset, no need to look at $A_X$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) $\mathbb{P}^2 \setminus (U_Z \cup U_Y)$ consists of the single point $(1:0:0)$. A divisor of the plane is a line, which can't be contained in this set,  so we haven't missed anything.

2) $H$ is the hyperplane where there is a pole, namely $v=0$, i.e., $Z=0$. But all lines in $\mathbb{P}^2$ are linearly equivalent, so if you only care about the class in the Picard group, it doesn't matter which one you choose.

Comment: André, so in the general case $\mathbb{P}^n$ it's also enough to consider only two charts, say $U_W$ and $U_Z$, right? Because in this  case $\mathbb{P}^n\setminus(U_W\cup U_Z)$ is codimension $2$ subvariety, so no divisor is contained in it.

Comment: @rmdmc89 Yes, exactly.